# Is there a method to detect sum of sinusoidal signal?

Tags: noise, filter-design

Consider we have $N$ samples. In that  $N$ samples we may have $M$ samples from sum of sinusoidal signal plus noise. Obviously $M<N$. In case $N=M$ we have only  $N$ noise samples. Let us assume $M$ is known i.e length or number of sinusoids samples if present, is known.

Is there a way to know which $M$ samples belong to the sum of sinusoidal signal?

If we know beforehand the waveform of the sum of sinusoidal signal, we can think of matched filter and choose the time sample at which the output of the matched filter is highest. However, in this case we do not even know the frequencies so there is no chance of using matched filter to get the best time estimate of the signal. We know Fourier transform gives the signal spectrum, but how can we answer the question from the spectrum?

One approach for this problem is to consider hypothesis testing by formulating a ratio of probability of signal plus noise and noise alone. Where the signal is sum of sinusoidal with amplitude and phase as a parameter. Next, one can use maximum likelihood estimate to estimate the parameters of the model. The frequency of the signal can be estimated from the peak of Fourier transform. The idea is to find the time samples at which the total power of the individual frequency components are maximum. If there are single frequency we would find the time samples at which the power of a fequency is maximum and if there are two sinusoids  then we would find the sample at which sum of power two frequency component are maximum. Therefore the steps can be:

1. Fink peak of the Fourier transfrom/periodogram to estimate frequency from given $M$ samples.
2. Find the phase  and amplitude from the maximum likelihood estimate and hence the sinusoidal signal.
3. Sunstract the  estimated signal from the given $M$ samples.
4. Continue steps 1 to 3 to find the peaks of the spectrum or periodogram

The above steps if performed for each set of $M$ samples  by moving forward one sample at a time. The sample at which the sum of the spectral power is high is the estimated time sample.

The code below shows the error of estimation for single sinusoids and two sinusoids respetively. The question is can we do something else for this problem? Further the code testFFTBeamFormerAdd is performing better than the existing one, is it useful?

```
function dspPythonCOde
clear all
close all
N = 1024;
M = 512;
mmm=30;
nnn=50;

    function[Ahat,phihat,power,periodog,omega_hat_index]=find_a_phi(x, n00, MM)


        seg_x = x([n00:(n00+M)-1]);
        xtemp=zeros(size(seg_x));
        for kk=1:1
            periodog =(abs(fft(seg_x-xtemp)).^2);
            [power(kk),omega_hat_index(kk)] = max(periodog(1:ceil(M/2)));
            omega_hat = 2*pi*omega_hat_index(kk)/MM;

            alpha1_hat = 2/M*sum(seg_x.*cos(omega_hat.*linspace(0,10,MM)));
            alpha2_hat = 2/M*sum(seg_x.*sin(omega_hat.*linspace(0,10,MM)));

            Ahat = sqrt((alpha1_hat).^2 + (alpha2_hat).^2);
            phihat = atan2(-alpha2_hat, alpha1_hat);
            xtemp=Ahat*cos(omega_hat.*linspace(0,10,MM)+phihat);
        end

    end
%return Ahat, phihat, omega_hat, periodogram, omega_hat_index

Nruns = 500;

error = zeros(1,Nruns);
error1 = zeros(1,Nruns);

for run =1:Nruns

    n0 = floor(mmm*rand(1,1) + nnn);

    x = randn(1,N);
    sinewave = 1*cos(2*pi*rand(1,1)*linspace(0,10,M));%+ .5*cos(2*pi*rand(1,1)*linspace(0,10,M));
    x(n0+1:(n0+M)) = x(n0+1:(n0+M)) + sinewave;

    peak = zeros(1,N-M+1);
    peak1=zeros(1,N-M+1);

    for n000=1:(N-M)
%         idx = (n000);
        [Ahat, phihat, power, periodog, omega_hat_index] = find_a_phi(x, n000, M);
        peak(n000) = sum((power));
        peak1(n000)=testFFTBeamFormerAdd(x(n000:(n000+M)-1));%testFFTBeamFormerSample(x(n000:(n000+M)-1));%
    end
    [~,ttt]=max(peak);
    [~,ttt1]=max(peak1);
    error(run) = ttt-n0-1;
    error1(run) = ttt1-n0-1;
end
%  plot(error)
 meanerror=mean(abs(error))
%  figure
%   plot(error1)
 meanerror1=mean(abs(error1))
 figure
 plot(abs(error))
 hold on
 plot(abs(error1),'r')
% print("Time delay estimate is " + max(peak) + ". Truth is " + (n0))
end
meanerror =

   13.5340


meanerror1 =

    4.8080



Published with MATLAB® R2020b
```

The code below is for two sinusoidals

````
function dspPythonCOde
clear all
close all
N = 1024;
M = 512;
mmm=30;
nnn=50;

    function[Ahat,phihat,power,periodog,omega_hat_index]=find_a_phi(x, n00, MM)


        seg_x = x([n00:(n00+M)-1]);
        xtemp=zeros(size(seg_x));
        for kk=1:2
            periodog =(abs(fft(seg_x-xtemp)).^2);
            [power(kk),omega_hat_index(kk)] = max(periodog(1:ceil(M/2)));
            omega_hat = 2*pi*omega_hat_index(kk)/MM;

            alpha1_hat = 2/M*sum(seg_x.*cos(omega_hat.*linspace(0,10,MM)));
            alpha2_hat = 2/M*sum(seg_x.*sin(omega_hat.*linspace(0,10,MM)));

            Ahat = sqrt((alpha1_hat).^2 + (alpha2_hat).^2);
            phihat = atan2(-alpha2_hat, alpha1_hat);
            xtemp=Ahat*cos(omega_hat.*linspace(0,10,MM)+phihat);
        end

    end
%return Ahat, phihat, omega_hat, periodogram, omega_hat_index

Nruns = 500;

error = zeros(1,Nruns);
error1 = zeros(1,Nruns);

for run =1:Nruns

    n0 = floor(mmm*rand(1,1) + nnn);

    x = randn(1,N);
    sinewave = .5*cos(2*pi*rand(1,1)*linspace(0,10,M))+ .5*cos(2*pi*rand(1,1)*linspace(0,10,M));
    x(n0+1:(n0+M)) = x(n0+1:(n0+M)) + sinewave;

    peak = zeros(1,N-M+1);
    peak1=zeros(1,N-M+1);

    for n000=1:(N-M)
%         idx = (n000);
        [Ahat, phihat, power, periodog, omega_hat_index] = find_a_phi(x, n000, M);
        peak(n000) = sum((power));
        peak1(n000)=testFFTBeamFormerAdd(x(n000:(n000+M)-1));%testFFTBeamFormerSample(x(n000:(n000+M)-1));%
    end
    [~,ttt]=max(peak);
    [~,ttt1]=max(peak1);
    error(run) = ttt-n0-1;
    error1(run) = ttt1-n0-1;
end
%  plot(error)
 meanerror=mean(abs(error))
%  figure
%   plot(error1)
 meanerror1=mean(abs(error1))
 figure
 plot(abs(error))
 hold on
 plot(abs(error1),'r')
% print("Time delay estimate is " + max(peak) + ". Truth is " + (n0))
end
meanerror =

   26.8840


meanerror1 =

   10.5140

```
````

Comment: The "subtract the largest component repeatedly" approach is pretty close to the best because the sinusoids are effectively orthogonal (unless they're really close to each other or to zero or $f_s/2$). Doing it jointly can be probably be done, but is going to be way more complex with no real benefit (that I can see).

Comment: @PeterK. Thank you so much for your comment. Further, would you please comment on the fact that testFFTBeamFormerAdd  is resonably better and thus  such alogorithm (testFFTBeamFormerAdd ) can be useful in any scenario? I understand I have not explained what is does yet.